# How to find out part of the url from within a Web API Action?

Tags: routes, controller, asp.net-web-api

In Web API, I have a UserController inside which there is an action as below:

```
[HttpGet]
public string SearchByEmail(string email)
{
    // how to get the sitename?
    return email;
}
```

I've added a Route to the WebApiConfig as below:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "SearchUserByEmail",
               routeTemplate: "{sitename}/User/SearchByEmail",
               defaults: new
               {
                   controller = "User",
                   action = "SearchByEmail"
               });
```

basically, the user can call the action using the below path:

```
/mysitename1/user/searchbyemail?email=lala@lala.com
```

How to find out the site name from within the action?

I've written the below method to retrieve it from within my Request:

```
private string GetSiteName()
        {
            return this.Request.RequestUri.Segments[1].Replace("/", String.Empty);
        }
```

But isn't there any better way in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Action in your UserController:

```
[HttpGet]
public string SearchByEmail([FromUri]string sitename, string email)
{
   //Do stuff with sitename
   return email;
}
```

Comment: The [FromUri] attribute is not strictly necessary, the above action should still work without it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the details from the Route Data present on the current request.

Request.GetRouteData().Values["sitename"].ToString()